# How to show phone number instead of email address in Messages?

Tags: ios, messages

On a iPhone 4s my text messages show my email address not my phone number . How do I change it everything I have read is telling me how to do from a newer phone

Comment: "...everything I have read is telling me how to do from a newer phone" As long as it's running iOS 8, the steps on how to accomplish this for a newer iPhone will be largely the same, if not exactly the same, as for an iPhone 4S.

Comment: The phone model isn't important here, but the iOS version. Which iOS version are you using and which procedures did you already try to solve the problem? Also, is this a problem on the sender side (your phone) or on the receiver side?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem after setting up a new iPhone.

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Scroll down and select the Messages subsection.
3. Tap Send & Receive.
4. Scroll down to "Start New Conversations From", and select your phone number instead of your email address.

Here's an article I wrote a while ago with a discussion on this topic: https://deciphertools.com/blog/2014_06_20_stop_sending_imessage_from_email/

Answer (score 0):

Go to "settings"- "messages"- send & receive then sign out with your apple ID, back out and then go back in. Sign in and it will give you the option to uncheck the email address. Hope it works.